# Vectorized evaluation of sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.Matern

Tags: python, scikit-learn, vectorization

It is unclear for me from the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.Matern.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.Matern.__call__) how the `__call__` function of the Matern kernel in `sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels` works.
In particular, I would like to build the matrix `K = k(x_i, x_j)` for all couples of elements `x_i, x_j`  in a grid `x`. The intuitive way, for me, would be to do a `meshgrid` operation and then feed it to the kernel. Apparently this does not work (see pictures), but with two nested loops I obtain what I expect (again see pictures). How do I avoid the double loop in the code below?

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import Matern
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 51
x = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
kernel = Matern(length_scale=1, nu=1.5)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, x)

# evaluate the kernel vectorially
k1 = kernel(xx, yy)

# evaluate the kernel with for loops
k2 = np.zeros([n, n])
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        k2[i, j] = kernel([[x[i]]], [[x[j]]])

plt.matshow(k1)
plt.matshow(k2)
```

[image] [image]

**Edit:**

I (almost) made this work by using

```
x_eval = np.array([x, x]).T
k1 = kernel(x_eval)
```

Still there is some non-negligible difference between the vectorized and loop-based versions. Some ideas why?

[image] [image] [image]

**Edit 2:**

The code to get `k1` in the **Edit** above is wrong, I checked with a self-made implementation of the Gaussian kernel `K(x_i, x_j) = exp(-(x_i - x_j)**2 / (2 * scale**2))` which is the same as the Matern covariance with parameter `nu=np.inf`. The value I obtain coincides with the for loop version, and is different than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct implementation:

```
x_eval = np.reshape(x, [n, 1])
k1 = kernel(x_eval)
```